# Problem calling google cloud run api url from jiofi network and jio hotspot

Tags: android, dns, google-cloud-run

I have deployed Nodejs api server on Google Cloud Run. And calling API from Android app. It works perfectly except for jiofi network and jio hotspot.
When calling api from jiofi internet it fails with following error.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "xxxxxx-service-xxxxxxx-uc.a.run.app": No address associated with hostname
```

Same GET api could not be called from Google Chrome using jiofi or jio hotspot network. While it works for all other internet connections.

Is there some configuration that could help with this issue. Can you please help to fix this problem.

Comment: This is not an issue with GCP but with the network. Maybe using the Google's DNS or a proxy.